# Can't wrap firebase function using firebase-function-testing

Tags: google-cloud-functions

When I use the `wrap` function from `firebase-functions-test` I got this error message

Error Message

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

> at isV2CloudFunction (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:49:26)
> at wrap (node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/main.js:32:9)

Test file code

```
const firebaseFunctionsTest = require("firebase-functions-test");
const {wrap} =  firebaseFunctionsTest()
describe('Firestore Function Test', ()=>{
    let wrappedFunction = wrap(firestoreFunction.firestoreFunction)

    beforeEach(()=>{    
        wrappedFunction()
    })

})
```

Function file code

```
exports.firestoreFunction = functions.firestore.document('/collection/doc').onCreate(
    async(snap, context)=>{
       //function logic
});

function functionA(){
  //function A logic
}

function functionB(){
  //function B logic
}

module.exports = {
  functionA,
  functionB
}
```

Comment: Have you already checked this [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test)? wrap requires you to declare and import the function in your test file code. Also, could you please include your `package.json` to check what dependencies version are you using.

Comment: yes, I have declared the function in the test file,
the problem is now solved by changing the exports of the function to be with the other functions in the `module.exports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file function, I have used two methods of export,
so in the test file when I call `firestoreFunction.firestoreFunction`
it will be **`undefined`**.

Changing the function file has solved it.

```
const firestoreFunction = functions.firestore.document('/collection/doc').onCreate(
    async(snap, context)=>{
       //function logic
});

function functionA(){
  //function A logic
}

function functionB(){
  //function B logic
}

module.exports = {
  firestoreFunction,
  functionA,
  functionB
}
```